# Finding the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(4x-3)(4x-1)}\,dx$.

Tags: definite-integrals

Which method that will be effective for solving this integral?

Comment: Did you try partial fractions?

Comment: It doesn't converge. You can use Cauchy's Principal Value.

Comment: I think the partial fractions will not give me the solution

Comment: @Ehegh yeah of course it would not give you the solution, since the integral doesn't converge

Comment: @Ehegh: Partial fractions is the standard elementary solution and *will* work. Of course, you have to realize that the function has vertical asymptotes at $\frac14$ and $\frac34$ and take these into account.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: how do you take the vertical asymptotes into account? Are you proposing the Cauchy Principal Value, because the integrals diverge in the standard sense.

Comment: @robjohn: In the usual first-year calculus fashion: split the thing into six integrals, each improper at one end. Of course you’ll find that several of the integrals diverge, but that’s what you should find. In other words, the standard elementary methods work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: okay, as long as you weren't saying that one could come up with a finite value for the integral without some sort of convention, such as the Cauchy Principal Value.

Comment: @robjohn: No, of course not. (And I’m bemused by comments like Aaron’s above.)

Comment: Please put the question in the question (as well as the title). On mobiles, the LaTeX of the title doesn't render.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated, the integral does not converge. It contains two singular points at which the integral does not converge: $x=\frac14$ and $x=\frac34$.

However, we can apply the Cauchy Principal Value. One way to compute this is using contour integration. We can use the contour

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]

$$
\small\color{#00A000}{iR[1,0]}\cup\color{#C00000}{\left[0,\frac14-\frac1R\right]}\cup\color{#00A000}{\frac14+\frac1Re^{i\pi[1,0]}}\cup\color{#C00000}{\left[\frac14+\frac1R,\frac34-\frac1R\right]}\cup\color{#00A000}{\frac34+\frac1Re^{i\pi[1,0]}}\cup\color{#C00000}{\left[\frac34+\frac1R,R\right]}\cup \color{#0000FF}{Re^{i\pi\left[0,\frac12\right]}}
$$
as $R\to\infty$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(4x-3)(4x-1)}
&=\pi i\left(\operatorname*{Res}_{z=1/4}\frac1{(4z-3)(4z-1)}+\operatorname*{Res}_{z=3/4}\frac1{(4z-3)(4z-1)}\right)\\
&+\int_0^\infty\frac1{(4ix-3)(4ix-1)}i\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\pi i\left(-\frac18+\frac18\right)+\frac18\left[\log\left(\frac{4ix-3}{4ix-1}\right)\right]_0^\infty\\
&=-\frac{\log(3)}{8}
\end{align}
$$
The contour contains no singularities, so the integral over the whole contour is $0$. The red pieces are the Cauchy Principal Value. The green pieces are the negative of the residues and integral above. The blue piece vanishes as $R\to\infty$.

In this case, the Cauchy Principal Value equals what one would get if one naively uses the formulas gotten by ignoring the singularities, but this is not always the case.

Comment: nice picture!${}$

Answer (score 8):

The integral does not converge because of the singularities.

To compute the integral between $a$ and $\infty$ for $a>\frac 34$, you can use the following method:

\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(4x-3)(4x-1)} dx
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{a}^N \frac{1}{(4x-3)(4x-1)} dx
\end{align}

Now use the fact that $$
\frac{1}{(4x-3)(4x-1)} =
\frac 12 \left(
\frac 1{4x-3} - \frac 1{4x-1}
\right)
$$
so that

\begin{align}
\int_{a}^N \frac{dx}{(4x-3)(4x-1)} 
&= \frac 12 \left(
\int_{a}^N \frac {dx}{4x-3} dx - \int_a^N \frac {dx}{4x-1} dx
\right) 
\\&= \frac 18\left(
\log \frac{|4N-3|}{|4a-3|} - \log \frac{|4N-1|}{|4a-1|}
\right)
\\&= \frac 18\left(
\log \frac{4N-3}{4N-1} - \log \frac{4a-3}{4a-1}\right)
 \to -\frac18 \log \frac{4a-3}{4a-1}
\end{align}

Comment: Neither of the integrals converge since each contains a singularity; one at $x=\frac34$ and one at $x=\frac14$.

Comment: @robjohn I fixed the typo, thanks.

Comment: What happens as $a\to\frac34^+$? $-\frac18\log\left(\frac{4a-3}{4a-1}\right)\to+\infty$

Comment: Look at the beginning of my post: "The integral does not converge because of the singularities. To compute the integral between $a$ and $\infty$ for $a>\frac 34$..."

Comment: Ah, I missed the change there.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{0 < a < \Lambda}$:

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\pp\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\dd x \over x - a}}
> =\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}\pars{\int_{0}^{a - \epsilon}{\dd x \over x - a}
> +\int_{a + \epsilon}^{\Lambda}{\dd x \over x - a}}
> =\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}
> \ln\pars{\verts{-\epsilon\bracks{\Lambda - a} \over -a\epsilon}}
> \\[5mm]&=\ln\pars{\Lambda - a \over a}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\pp\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{4x - 3}\pars{4x - 1}}}
={1 \over 8}\,\lim_{\Lambda\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{
\pp\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\dd x \over x - 3/4}
-\pp\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\dd x \over x - 1/4}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 8}\,\lim_{\Lambda\ \to\ \infty}
\bracks{\ln\pars{\Lambda - 3/4 \over 3/4} - \ln\pars{\Lambda - 1/4 \over 1/4}}
={1 \over 8}\,\lim_{\Lambda\ \to\ \infty}
\ln\pars{{1 \over 3}\,{\Lambda - 3/4 \over \Lambda - 1/4}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large -\,{1 \over 8}\,\ln\pars{3}} \approx {\tt -0.1373}
\end{align}